# Why won't my nested React components render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm having a problem with my React component. The nested children of my component `ControlPanel` don't seem to be rendering. Here is my code:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ControlPanel>
          <CustomerDisplay />
        </ControlPanel>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have the following two lines at the top of this file:

```
import ControlPanel from './components/control_panel';

import CustomerDisplay from './components/customer_display';
```

And here is my `ControlPanel` Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules';
import styles from './styles.scss';

const ControlPanel = () => {
    return (
      <div className="control_panel" id="control_panel">

      </div>
    );
}

export default CSSModules(ControlPanel, styles);
```

I have tried:

- Calling the component as a full HTML tag (opening & closing)
- Nesting the `CustomerDisplay` component in the `ControlPanel` component (in the `ControlPanel`'s index.jsx file)

I know that nesting component's is possible. I've seen it done. For some reason it just won't work for me.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To allow components to contain children and render them correctly, you have to use `this.props.children`. This is passed to all components with children as a prop and contains the children of the component, as explained by [the React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html):

> ### Containment
>
> Some components don't know their children ahead of time. This is especially common for components like `Sidebar` or `Dialog` that represent generic "boxes".
>
> We recommend that such components **use the special `children` prop to pass children elements directly into their output**:
>
> ```
> function FancyBorder(props) {
>     return (
>       <div className={'FancyBorder FancyBorder-' + props.color}>
>         {props.children}
>       </div>
>     );
> }
> ```
>
> This lets other components pass arbitrary children to them by nesting the JSX
>
> ```
> function WelcomeDialog() {
>     return (
>       <FancyBorder color="blue">
>         <h1 className="Dialog-title">
>           Welcome
>         </h1>
>         <p className="Dialog-message">
>           Thank you for visiting our spacecraft!
>         </p>
>       </FancyBorder>
>     );
> }
> ```

As described in the documentation, some components don't know their children ahead of time -- they may be generic wrappers or boxes of content that vary, which is what your `ControlPanel` is. So, to render the children of your component, you must render the children from the `children` prop explicitly in the parent's `render` method. Thus, apply it like this to your code:

```
const ControlPanel = (props) => {
    return (
      <div className="control_panel" id="control_panel">
        {props.children}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Notice how `props.children` is rendered (not `this.props.children` because it is a function component).

Comment: just saying, "this." is not needed not because is a stateless component, it isn't needed because it is a function and not a class, classes can be stateless too.

Comment: @PabloMáximo I think that was just a brainfart on my part. Thanks for the heads up, updated.

Answer (score 4):

You can access the nested elements through props. So in your case do this:

```
const ControlPanel = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="control_panel" id="control_panel">
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to render the children in `ControlPanel`

```
const ControlPanel = ({ children }) => {
    return (
      <div className="control_panel" id="control_panel">
        {children}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function FancyBorder(props) {
  return (
    <div className={'FancyBorder FancyBorder-' + props.color}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function WelcomeDialog() {
  return (
    <FancyBorder color="blue">
        <h1 className="Dialog-title">
           Welcome
        </h1>
        <p className="Dialog-message">
           Thank you for visiting our spacecraft!
        </p>
    </FancyBorder>
  );
}
```

Anything inside the`<FancyBorder>`JSX tag gets passed into the FancyBorder component as `children`prop. Since FancyBorder renders `{props.children}` inside a `<div>`, the passed elements appear in the final output.

This is what I was looking after, check it out here 
 https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

Your App.js (I understand that it is your JSX Index) should be:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <ControlPanel>
      <CustomerDisplay />
    </ControlPanel>
  </div>
);
}
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('YOUR_ROOT_ID'));
```

Try to add `export default` before `class` (in all your components).