# How do I pass in a component to a component in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

What I want to be able to do is pass in another component that would replace the buttons using this syntax.

```
<EmailDrop>
   <AnotherComponent />
</EmailDrop>
```

I imagine there must be a way to do this but I am struggling to even know what to google to find out. Do I pass a function into it as a prop?

I feel like I am missing something really basic.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class EmailDrop extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            showMenu: false,
        };

        this.showMenu = this.showMenu.bind(this);
        this.closeMenu = this.closeMenu.bind(this);
    }

    showMenu(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({ showMenu: true }, () => {
            document.addEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
        });
    }

    closeMenu(event) {

        if (!this.dropdownMenu.contains(event.target)) {

            this.setState({ showMenu: false }, () => {
                document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
            });

        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.showMenu}>
                    Show menu
                </button>

                {
                    this.state.showMenu
                        ? (
                            <div
                                className="menu"
                                ref={(element) => {
                                    this.dropdownMenu = element;
                                }}
                            >
                                <button> Menu item 1 </button>
                                <button> Menu item 2 </button>
                                <button> Menu item 3 </button>
                            </div>
                        )
                        : null
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default EmailDrop
```

Comment: look for react-HOC.

Comment: Prop children or render props

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need manually created event listeners in React.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why won't my nested React components render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712494/why-wont-my-nested-react-components-render)

Comment: What exactly does  `<AnotherComponent />` replace?

Comment: How else do I create event listeners if not manually?

Comment: More specifically, `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener ` are not usually used in React.

Comment: How would I add and remove event listeners to the whole document in a react way?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass down child components through a parent component using the children props. In this scenario,

```
<EmailDrop>
  <AnotherComponent />
</EmailDrop>
```

`AnotherComponent` is part of the `children` props of `EmailDrop`, and therefore, when you are working on the component logic for `EmailDrop`, you can actually access `AnotherComponent` and conditionally render it if it exists:

```
render() {
  const { children } = this.props;  

  return ( 
    <>
      {
        children 
         ? children 
         : <Buttons /> 
      }
    </>
  )
}
```